# Delete Protected WMA

Tags: windows-explorer, search

I have several hundred protected WMA files that I don't want to keep, spread in a several level deep folder structure. Is there an easy way to detect these files and delete them?

There are also unprotected WMA and MP3 which I intend to keep, side by side with the protected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this method myself since I do not have any DRM protected files, but give this a try:

1. From the Windows search tool, scan your drive for all WMA files; type *.wma in the file name field.
2. View the results in 'Details view'.
3. Right-click the column headers bar (where it says Filename, Type, Size, ...), select 'More', then add 'Protected'.
4. Click the 'Protected' tab to sort.
5. Highlight all files with protection (click/shift-click) then delete.

Comment: Good idea. I was trying to find a command line solution but this one should work well. Thanks!